# Nodejs regexp validation for sip URI string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

`var uriRegExp = /^(sip):\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[- ]?([0-9]{3})[- ]?([0-9]{4})@\w+(\ w+)*(\.\w)(\.\w{2,3})+$/;`

Is this a correct regular expression for validating the string

> **sip:1-999-123-4567@voip-provider.example.net** ?

Comment: Did you _try_ validating that string with that regular expression?

Comment: You can test this on any online regex tester website. here is one of them [link](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @KukicVladimir Thanks for the link. Its not matching to my string. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this regex does not match your string.

If you want to know why you could have a look at https://regex101.com/r/EC0xFN/1 .
There you can interactively build and check your regex with different input strings.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Yes, but due to the lack of reputation I was not allowed to post a comment at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sip URI validator, that i have created, using regular expression.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "sip:+91989556926@test.est.test.com";
    var regExp = /^(sip):(\S+[0-9])@\S+(\w+([.-]?\w+)*).(\w{2,3})$/;
    var result = regExp.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Please check the link.

[https://regex101.com/r/5vMfI9/4][1]